# How to show that the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^n}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Show that $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^n}$$

I try to use the D'Alembert theorem bit I think to is not the good strategy, I think to the comparation test is the right way but, this is correct?
$$\frac{1}{n^n} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$$
Any hint or suggestion I will be very grateful

Comment: The series converge so rapidly that everything will work:  comparison,  D'Alembert, Cauchy will do.

Comment: Fun fact: This is the so-called [Sophomore's dream!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said youself, for any $n\geq 2$,

$$\frac{1}{n^n}\leq\frac{1}{n^2}.$$

It follows by comparison that it converges. As you can see, you already had the solution, well done!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^n} < 1 + \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} = \frac32.$

**Edit**
Or, the sum is $\displaystyle < 1 + \frac{1}{4} + \sum_{k=3}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n} = \frac{5}{4} + \left(\frac{1}{27} \times \frac{3}{2}\right)$

and so on.